# Entity Framework Core: Restricting foreign key columns from being equal to each other

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.2 to manage a SQL Server database of traded currencies. There are two entities in the model. The first is `Currency`, which specifies a trade-able currency, and the other is `CurrencyPair`, which specifies a pair of currencies that can be exchanged for one another.

```
public class Currency
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<CurrencyPair> Pairs
    {
        get { PairsAsBase?.Concat( PairsAsQuote ?? new CurrencyPair[0] ); }
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<CurrencyPair> PairsAsBase { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<CurrencyPair> PairsAsQuote { get; set; }
}

public class CurrencyPair
{
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ulong BaseCurrencyId { get; set; }
    public ulong QuoteCurrencyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Currency BaseCurrency { get; set; }
    public virtual Currency QuoteCurrency { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to constrain the `CurrencyPair` table to disallow rows from having the same `Currency` for both `BaseCurrency` and `QuoteCurrency` fields. That is, if a specific currency has `Id = 1`, then a currency pair specifying `BaseCurrencyId = 1` and `QuoteCurrencyId = 1` would not be allowed.

Here is my `DbContext.OnModelCreating` implementation:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating( ModelBuilder modelBuilder )
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>().HasAlternateKey(x => x.Name);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>()
                .HasMany(x => x.PairsAsBase)
                .WithOne(x => x.BaseCurrency)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.BaseCurrencyId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Currency>()
                .HasMany(x => x.PairsAsQuote)
                .WithOne(x => x.QuoteCurrency)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.QuoteCurrencyId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyPair>().HasKey(x => x.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyPair>()
                .HasOne(x => x.BaseCurrency)
                .WithMany(x => x.PairsAsBase)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.BaseCurrencyId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyPair>()
                .HasOne(x => x.QuoteCurrency)
                .WithMany(x => x.PairsAsQuote)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.QuoteCurrencyId);
}
```

**TL;DR**: How can I ensure that two foreign key columns in a table do not both reference the same entity (using Entity Framework Core 2.2)?

Comment: I would say that there is no really good way to do this. You can use something like triggers to restrict it, but I personally wouldn't do this. Did you consider just validating this data before it comes to your database?

Comment: validation client side and check constraint in the DB.  which RDBMS?

Comment: This is trivial to do with a simple `CHECK` constraint on the database. Something along the lines of this will do: `ALTER TABLE CurrencyPair ADD CONSTRAINT CK_CurrencyPair_DifferentCurrencies CHECK (BaseCurrency <> QuoteCurrency) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK there is no good way to enforce your rule at the model builder lvl.
The next best thing would be to intercept SQL commands that could generate faulty data through an ef context, but the API isnt mature enough to make this an easy option.

In my opinion, the only options that you have left have no relation whatsoever to EF:

- Constrain: Enforce the rule on your DB schema, eg. through a `CHECK` constraint
- Validate: Enforce the rule at domain model level, eg. by intercepting the setters for both properties in the class and validating their values.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try Global query filters, this should help you protect some unwanted to be show up when you query

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CurrencyPair>().HasQueryFilter(p => p.BaseCurrency != p.QuoteCurrency);
```

Data will still store in your table but it not show up when you using it.